# Open Suse 12.1 rescue console language?

Tags: opensuse

How can I change the keyboard layout from the rescue console in Open Suse 12.1 to a german keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you boot openSUSE the grub boot loader appears (where you can choose which operating system you want to use). At the bottom you can see some key bindings. You should be able to press "F4" in order to change the keyboard layout.